# Could not connect to mongo db replica set hosting on docker on Ubuntu using localhost

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu-18.04, mongo-cxx-driver

So, I am running my mongod replica set instances on docker. I am trying to establish the connection from my c++ application. Here is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
    api:
        hostname: api
        build: .
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
            - 8001:8001
            - 8500:8500
        depends_on:
            - mongo1
            - mongo2
            - mongo3
    mongo1:
        hostname: mongo1
        container_name: mongo1
        image: mongo:4.0-xenial
        expose:
            - 27017
        ports:
            - 27011:27017
        restart: always
        entrypoint: ['/usr/bin/mongod', '--bind_ip_all', '--replSet', 'rs0']
    mongo2:
        hostname: mongo2
        container_name: mongo2
        image: mongo:4.0-xenial
        expose:
            - 27017
        ports:
            - 27012:27017
        restart: always
        entrypoint: ['/usr/bin/mongod', '--bind_ip_all', '--replSet', 'rs0']
    mongo3:
        hostname: mongo3
        container_name: mongo3
        image: mongo:4.0-xenial
        expose:
            - 27017
        ports:
            - 27013:27017
        restart: always
        entrypoint: ['/usr/bin/mongod', '--bind_ip_all', '--replSet', 'rs0']
```

I could establish the connection using host ip_address, but as the ip_address changes from network to network, it's not a feasible soultion if each developer needs to change ip_address everytime. Below is the connection string that's worked for me.

```
auto mongocxx_uri = "mongodb://192.168.18.4:27011,192.168.18.4:27012,192.168.18.4:27013/?replicaSet=rs0";
```

Below is the desired connection string or something which can be configured once or automatically.

```
auto mongocxx_uri = "mongodb://localhost:27011,localhost:27012,localhost:27013/?replicaSet=rs0";
```

But I am looking something with localhost, I can connect to individual instance using localhost but not for replica set.

I have tried to add alias for host names(mongo1, mongo2, mongo3) in  /etc/hosts file but
that didn't work for me.

I assumed that docker uses /etc/mongod.conf file and tried change the bind_ip like below but that also did not work for me.

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

```
Docker version 19.03.13
MongoDB server version: 4.0.21
Mongocxx 3.6.0 version
```

Below are the /etc/hosts file on my laptop

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   xxxxxxx
127.0.0.1   mongo1, mongo2, mongo3

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Below is the output from docker ps command

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                NAMES

fea5883e73ae        mongo:4.0-xenial     "/usr/bin/mongod --b…"   43 minutes ago      Up 43 minutes       0.0.0.0:27013->27017/tcp                                             mongo3
5a3846f44dfd        mongo:4.0-xenial     "/usr/bin/mongod --b…"   43 minutes ago      Up 43 minutes       0.0.0.0:27011->27017/tcp                                             mongo1
450f21091acc        mongo:4.0-xenial     "/usr/bin/mongod --b…"   43 minutes ago      Up 43 minutes       0.0.0.0:27012->27017/tcp                                             mongo2
```

Can someone let me know what am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: if you connect to any of those, and run `rs.status()` what it the output?

Comment: I just update my question rs.status() command ouput.

Comment: Oh, i didn't pay real attention, so you can connect, and it connects to the primary using the ip values. But not using localhost? then you can probably remove `rs.status()`

Comment: Yes, when I connect using ip values, i needed to change the hostnames to ip_address:port. Likewise I tried to use localhost:port but that didn't work for me and got " No host described in new configuration on 1 for replica set maps to this node".